# Why is there no displacement in height in the texture after adding the normal and height maps?

Tags: texturing

[image]
The plane is just flat without any height based off the normal and height map texture used in the PBSDF.
Ive added the bump node and normal node for the displacement and normal maps yet there is no bumps on the plane. There is also pixelated lines on the surface of the plane when the strength of the bump node is 1. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: do you use cycles? does your material have the settings "displacement only" on?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the vector into the Normal input of the shader. Using altered normals in materials by definition does not deform the mesh. To deform the mesh with a material, send the vector from a Displacement node into the Displacement input on the Output node, and set the material’s displacement mode to “Displacement only” or “Bump and displacement. Note that this will only work in Cycles, and will not generate new vertices: the mesh must be subdivided quite a bit for any noticeable effect.

To displace a mesh with a texture without using Cycles, use the Displacement modifier instead. Note that this will not generate new vertices, just like the last example.